# Пересечение нескольких множеств

Tags: java, сравнение, множества, set

У меня есть 3 строки, которые задает пользователь. Пускай это будет:

```
мать
матрас
трамвай
```

Эти 3 строки я преобразовала в 3 разных множества `Set`, для того чтобы определить уникальные символы.

Теперь мне надо их сравнить так, чтобы в результате программа вывела только те уникальные символы, которые встречаются одновременно во всех 3 строках.

И вывод должен быть в данном случае:

```
т м а
```

Каким образом можно сравнить  множества и вывести результат не используя Stream API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться методом `java.util.Set#retainAll`:

```
package com.somepackage;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Character> ch1 =
                "мать".chars()
                        .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Character> ch2 =
                "матрас".chars()
                        .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Character> ch3 =
                "трамвай".chars()
                        .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        Set<Character> newSet = 
                new HashSet<>(ch1);
        newSet.retainAll(ch2);
        newSet.retainAll(ch3);
        System.out.println(newSet);
    }

}
```

Результат:

```
[а, т, м]
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте `Set<Character>`, и добавьте в него символы из всех остальных множеств, так вы получите множество уникальный символов для всех входных слов.

Затем, для каждого символа из получившегося множества, проверьте, что данный символ входит в каждое из множеств символов для каждого отдельного слова.

Если символ удовлетворяет условию, то выведите его в терминал.
Код решения ниже. Предполагается, что списки `ch1, ch2, ch3` инициализированы, согласно коду вопроса.

```
Set<Character> 
    firstWordLetters = new HashSet<>(),
    secondWordLetters = new HashSet<>(),
    thirdWordLetters = new HashSet<>(),
    commonLetters = new HashSet<>();

firstWordLetters.addAll(ch1);
secondWordLetters.addAll(ch2);
thirdWordLetters.addAll(ch3);

commonLetters.addAll(firstWordLetters);
commonLetters.addAll(secondWordLetters);
commonLetters.addAll(thirdWordLetters);

for(Character letter : commonLetters){
    if(firstWordLetters.contains(letter)
        && secondWordLetters.contains(letter)
        && thirdWordLetters.contains(letter)){
            System.out.print(letter + " ");
        } 
}
```